# How to force subcategory to sort under parent category in category list

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Did anyone realize that In OPENCART category listing page. 
If we assign a category into a parent category for example:

```
Chicken -> Animal(Parent category)
Duck -> Animal(Parent category)
```

the display in listing would be something like

```
   Name              Sort Order 
  Animal                  11
  Animal > Chicken         2
  Animal > Duck            1
```

but what I wanted to achieve is to sort the sub category with the current format. That means it should be sorted as

```
   Name              Sort Order 
  Animal                  11
  Animal > Duck            1
  Animal > Chicken         2
```

I had went through this site:
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/commit/80841d0e2580037f039f542eb76a6a5858d4536b#upload/admin/model/catalog/category.php

It is able to be sorted as I like according to sort order BUT however, the subcategory is not stick to the parent category..

May I know how can I achieve that?

ADDED === 4 DEC ====

http://www.openx.com.au/demo1541/admin      id/pw: demo/demo

just exactly like this site. 
I am able to drag and drop and save. but cant be able to make the subcategories sorted as he did.

Comment: What version of OC are You using? As I am suspicious about Your statement and I think the sorting of subcategories is working correctly...

Comment: The latest version. Sorry for the question that misunderstood reader. Im looking forward a sort for Example. Animal is parent. Chicken and Duck would definitely be sorted under the Animal in the category list regardless of sort order. But then added another condition. between duck and chicken, I wanted to sort within the subcategories between duck and chicken. In OC cannot be sorted for subcategories even the sort order is from small to big. The subcategories will be sorted according to name.